# Where not exist and type =""

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve a list of steam apps where the type="game" and where it does not exist in the table "match_connections"

What I tried

```
SELECT * FROM steam_apps t1 WHERE type="game" AND
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM match_connections t2 WHERE t1.appid = t2.steamid)
  ¨
```

DB Layout:

**steam_apps**

- ID
- appid
- type
- name

**igdb_games**

- ID
- gameid
- name

**match_connections**

- ID
- igdbid (gameid of igdb_games)
- steamid (appid of steam_apps)
- igdb_name
- steam_name

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just found it:

```
SELECT * FROM steam_apps t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM match_connections t2 WHERE t1.appid = t2.steamid)
  AND type="game"
```